# Pre pulling docker images in AMI to reduce node and pod fresh start time slows down it's execution when using nvidia-docker with GPU enabled pods

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, tensorflow, kubernetes

Using Kubernetes v1.16 on AWS I am facing a weird issue while trying to reduce the time it takes to start a pod on a newly spawned node.

By default, a node AMI does not contains any pre cached docker image, so when a pod is scheduled onto it, its 1st job is to pull the docker image.

Pulling large docker image can take a while, so the pod takes a long time to run.

Recently I come with the idea of pre-pulling my large docker image right into the AMI, so that when a pod is scheduled onto it, it won't have to download it. Turns out a lot of people was doing this dor a while, known as "baking AMI":

- https://runnable.com/blog/how-we-pre-bake-docker-images-to-reduce-infrastructure-spin-up-time
- https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kube-aws/issues/505
- https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/3378

My issue is that when I generate an AMI with my large image onto it and use this AMI, everything works as expected and the docker image is not downloaded as already present so the pod starts almost in 1 second but the pod itself runs 1000 times slower than if the docker image was not pre pulled on the AMI.

What I am doing:

- start a base working AMI on an EC2 instance
- ssh onto it
- run docker pull myreposiroty/myimage
- right click on the EC2 instance from AWS console & generate an AMI

If I don't prepull my docker image, then it's running normally, only if i prepull it, using the generated a new AMI then eben if its running in a second the container will be slow like never before.

My docker image use GPU resources and it is based on tensorflow/tensorflow:1.14.0-gpu-py3 image.It seems to be relates to the use of combined nvidia-docker & tensorflow om GPU enabled EC2.

Id anyone have an idea from where this extreme running latency comes from it would be much appreciated.

**EDIT #1**

Since then I am now using Packer to build my AMI.
Here is my template file:

```
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "amazon-ebs",
      "access_key": "{{user `aws_access_key`}}",
      "secret_key": "{{user `aws_secret_key`}}",
      "ami_name": "compute-{{user `environment_name`}}-{{timestamp}}",
      "region": "{{user `region`}}",
      "instance_type": "{{user `instance`}}",
      "ssh_username": "admin",
      "source_ami_filter": {
        "filters": {
          "virtualization-type": "hvm",
          "name": "debian-stretch-hvm-x86_64-gp2-*",
          "root-device-type": "ebs"
        },
        "owners":"379101102735",
        "most_recent": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "execute_command": "sudo env {{ .Vars }} {{ .Path }}",
      "scripts": [
        "ami/setup_vm.sh"
      ],
      "type": "shell",
      "environment_vars": [
        "ENVIRONMENT_NAME={{user `environment_name`}}",
        "AWS_ACCOUNT_ID={{user `aws_account_id`}}",
        "AWS_REGION={{user `region`}}",
        "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID={{user `aws_access_key`}}",
        "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY={{user `aws_secret_key`}}",
        "DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME={{user `docker_image_name`}}"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "post-processors": [
    {
      "type": "manifest",
      "output": "ami/manifest.json",
      "strip_path": true
    }
  ],
  "variables": {
    "aws_access_key": "{{env `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`}}",
    "aws_secret_key": "{{env `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`}}",
    "environment_name": "",
    "region": "eu-west-1",
    "instance": "g4dn.xlarge",
    "aws_account_id":"",
    "docker_image_name":""
  }
}
```

and here is the associated script to configure the AMI for Docker & Nvidia Docker:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /tmp

export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
export APT_LISTCHANGES_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# docker
apt-get update
apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable"
apt-get update
apt-get install -y docker-ce
usermod -a -G docker $USER

# graphical drivers
apt-get install -y software-properties-common
wget http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/440.64/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.64.run
bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.64.run -sZ

# nvidia-docker
distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID)
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | apt-key add -
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/$distribution/nvidia-docker.list | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list
apt-get update
apt-get install -y nvidia-container-toolkit
apt-get install -y nvidia-docker2
cat > /etc/docker/daemon.json <<EOL
{
    "default-runtime": "nvidia",
    "runtimes": {
        "nvidia": {
            "path": "/usr/bin/nvidia-container-runtime",
            "runtimeArgs": []
        }
    }
}
EOL
systemctl restart docker

# enable nvidia-persistenced service
cat > /etc/systemd/system/nvidia-persistenced.service <<EOL
[Unit]
Description=NVIDIA Persistence Daemon
Wants=syslog.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/nvidia-persistenced/nvidia-persistenced.pid
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced --verbose
ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -rf /var/run/nvidia-persistenced

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOL
systemctl enable nvidia-persistenced

# prepull docker
apt-get install -y python3-pip
pip3 install awscli --upgrade
aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com
docker pull $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com/$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$ENVIRONMENT_NAME

# Clean up
apt-get -y autoremove
apt-get -y clean
```

Anyway, as soon as I put this line:

```
docker pull $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com/$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$ENVIRONMENT_NAME
```

I am facing the same weird issue, when pods are scheduled on nodes booted from this AMI, it says "image already present on machine", so it don't pull it again, but then the container is slow as hell when using TensorFlow, for eg. ts.Session() takes something like a minute to run.

**EDIT #2**

Adding extra information regarding what is executed on the pod:

Dockerfile

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:1.14.0-gpu-py3
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

main.py

```
import tensorflow as tf

config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
return tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph(), config=config)
```

Only with those lines TF Session initialization takes up to 1 mins to be done when the image is prepulled vs. 1 second when the image is not.

Comment: You mention that your pod gets very slow when you pre-pulled the image. What tests are you making to measure that and how can you be sure that the pod is slow and not the node itself?

Comment: Hi @mWatney well, I ssh on the node, perform htop and everything is normal. Even when I right into the container itself using kubectl exec -it I see that the i/o are normal for CPU, Memory etc... When I do nvidia-smi it works, and the memory of the GPU get some data, but very slowly. It's related to the GPU part of the code, as CPU part of the code run well...

Comment: Nvidia driver issue maybe? Maybe what you're wget'ing is not the right/updated file?

Comment: Hi, well... when I just remove the ´docker pull ...´ line then everything works like a charm, and more over. when it's there, then Kubernetes describe command tells me "image already present on machine" which means that the image prepulled is correct.

Comment: How big is the image and how long is your performance test? Maybe letting k8s pull it leaves the image in fs cache where it doesn't need to get downloaded from EBS. So basically you're seeing the image being downloaded from EBS. What's your EBS configuration?

Comment: Try pre-warming the EBS volume attached to your EC2 instance `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/xvdX bs=1M`

There's an initial performance penalty when creating a new EBS based on a snapshot due to data being stored in S3 and streamed to the volume after the creation of the instance..

Comment: If you delete the deployment and redeploy it, does it keep the same overhead? If not this likely confirms it is related to some kind of initial ineffecient condition exsiting on node start such as suggested by @kichik

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely due to the new instance not having "fully downloaded" all parts of the disk. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-initialize.html has details on this.

> For volumes that were created from snapshots, the storage blocks must be pulled down from Amazon S3 and written to the volume before you can access them. This preliminary action takes time and can cause a significant increase in the latency of I/O operations the first time each block is accessed. Volume performance is achieved after all blocks have been downloaded and written to the volume.

When the image is fully downloaded from S3, I assume everything will return to normal speed.

Comment: Good one. Instance monitoring should prove.